# Can I reduce this code with the same result?

Tags: java

I'm trying to reduce code to make my everything look cleaner and nice but I do not know how to change this code so that the function stays the same but with less code. I am also new to java so if there are alternative ways for me to write this code with the same output I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me how

```
 static class Action4 implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

        String name = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();

        if (name.equals("Test1")) {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name ");

            String day;
            int totalCost;
            int visitors;

            day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what day you'd like to attend ");

            visitors = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many people are visiting "));

            totalCost = visitors * 20;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "  You are attending the  " + name + "  On  " + day + visitors + "  attending  " + "total cost " + totalCost);
        } else {

            if (name.equals("test2")) {
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name ");

                String day;
                day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what day you'd like to attend ");
                int visitors;
                visitors = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many people are visiting "));

                int totalCost;
                totalCost = visitors * 17;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "  You are attending the  " + name + "  On  " + day + visitors + "  attending  " + "total cost " + totalCost);
            } else {

                if (name.equals("test3")) {
                    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name ");

                    String day;
                    day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what day you'd like to attend ");
                    int visitors;
                    visitors = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many people are visiting "));

                    int totalCost;
                    totalCost = visitors * 22;

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "  You are attending the  " + name + "  On  " + day + visitors + "  attending  " + "total cost " + totalCost);
                } else {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input!");

                }
            }
```

Comment: Most obvious change: use `else if`, not `else { if`.

Comment: This question is better suited to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

split your code into separate methods and use a switch case (if java >= 7):

```
static class Action4 implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

        String name = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();

        switch(name) {
            case "test1": 
                process(20);
                break;
            case "test2": 
                process(17);
                break;
            case "test3": 
                process(22);
                break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input!");
        }
    }

    public function getInput(int factor) {

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name ");

            String day;
            int totalCost;
            int visitors;

            day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what day you'd like to attend ");

            visitors = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many people are visiting "));

            totalCost = visitors * factor;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "  You are attending the  " + name + "  On  " + day + visitors + "  attending  " + "total cost " + totalCost);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Action4 implements ActionListener {
    String name = null;
    String day;
    int totalCost;
    int visitors;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        name = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();
        if (name.equals("Test1")) {
            init(20);
        } else if (name.equals("test2")) {
            init(17);
        } else if (name.equals("test3")) {
            init(22);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input!");
        }
    }

    private void init(int value) {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name ");
        day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what day you'd like to attend ");
        visitors = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many people are visiting "));
        totalCost = visitors * value;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "  You are attending the  " + name + "  On  " + day + visitors + "  attending  " + "total cost " + totalCost);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works as yours

```
static class Action4 implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

    String name = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name ");
    String day;
    int totalCost;
    int visitors;
    int multiplier = 0;
    day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what day you'd like to attend ");
    visitors = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many people are visiting "));
    if (name.equals("Test1"))
        multiplier =  20;
    else if (name.equals("test2"))
        multiplier =  17;  
    else if (name.equals("test3"))
        multiplier =  22;
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input!");
    totalCost = visitors * multiplier;
    if(multiplier != 0)
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "  You are attending the  " + name + "  On  " + day + visitors + "  attending  " + "total cost " + totalCost);
}
```

Comment: small problem, it lets the user enter any word in the textfield, it should only let them enter test1,test2,test3, and the wrong input shows up at the end, it should show up if the user enters anything other than test1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that whenever you have a series of options you consider using an `enum`. This allows neater encapsulation and it's much easier to add new entries without having to change any other code.

```
public enum Test {
    TEST1("test1", 20),
    TEST2("test2", 17),
    TEST3("test3", 22);

    private final String name;
    private final int costPerVisitor;

    private Test(String name, int costPerVisitor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.costPerVisitor = costPerVisitor;
    }

    public static Optional<Test> getTestWithName(String name) {
        for (Test test: values()) {
            if (test.name.equals(name))
                return Optional.of(test);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public int getTotalCost(int visitors) {
        return visitors * costPerVisitor;
    }
}
```

This can be used by:

```
Optional<Test> possibleTest = Test.getTestWithName(name);
if (possibleTest.isPresent()) {
    ...
    int totalCost = possibleTest.get().getTotalCost(visitor);
} else {
    showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input!");
}
```

It uses `Optional` but you could just as easily (though with less clarity) use `null` to mean "no test with that name".

Note that in your case you could avoid the `name` field altogether and use `name().toLower()`.